# Why always need [&] when using recursion with lambda?

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda

I am new to lambda expression ,When I wrote little program like this :

```
function<int(int)> test=[](int i){
    if (i<3) 
        return i;
    else 
        return test(i-1);
    };

//call 
test(5);
```

And the error message be something like this :

> lambda.cpp:36:16: error: ‘test’ is not captured
>            return test(i-1);
>
> lambda.cpp:32:31: note: the lambda has no capture-default
>        function test=[](int i){
>
> lambda.cpp:32:24: note: ‘std::function test’ declared here
>        function test=[](int i){

And when I do add `[&]` which captures everything out of scope by reference or even more specific `[&test]` ,the code works totally fine.

I was wondering why we need to do this,When we use normal function like this

```
int test(int i){
    if (i<3) return i;
    else return test(i-1);
}
```

We don't have to worry about this kind of situation(in this case only pass `i-1` ,Why do we always need to add additional argument when using lambda expression?What's under the hood?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal functions do not capture anything. `test` is globally (actually in the namespace) available.  That's why

```
int test(int i){
    if (i<3) return i;
    else return test(i-1);
}
```

works.

When you define a local variable in a scope in which you define a lambda you'll need to tell the lambda to capture (copy) that variable (in your case the local variable `test` happens to be a `std::function`), otherwise you cannot access it.

`[&test]` or `[&]` are not arguments, but telling the compiler you want to copy a reference to the local variable `test` or all local variable used, respectively.

Note that you could indeed pass test as an argument to itself  when calling it, but this is very cumbersome to do in C++ (and probably off the point here).

Comment: Maybe add a mention of capturing by value `=` as well as reference `&`, just for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Whereas call of lambda look like function, lambda are more similar to struct/class functor, but doesn't have indeed self reference with `this`:

```
struct Lambda
{
    constexpr int operator()(int i) const {
        if (i<3) return i;
        else return test(i-1); // Cannot access to variable test
                               // No this equivalent for lambda
    }
};

std::function<int(int)> test = Lamdba{};
```

With capture (`[&]`), it becomes:

```
struct Lambda
{
    std::function<int(int)>& test;

    constexpr int operator()(int i) const {
        if (i<3) return i;
        else return test(i-1); // The captured std::function,
                               // not necessary related to this instance
    }
};

std::function<int(int)> test = Lamdba{test};
```

`this` in lambda, refer to the instance class englobing the lambda, (if any).

Possible way to handle recursion with lamdba (without transforming it into std::function) is Y-combinator, something like

```
auto f = [](auto f, int i){
        if (i<3) return i;
        else return f(i-1); // The parameter which is expected to be the lambda 
    };
auto test = [f](int) { return f(t, i); };
auto res = test(42);
```

Comment: _"Possible way to handle recursion with lamdba (**without transforming it into `std::function`**)"_  - I was about to ask a question if that's possible - and your answer lead me to this proposal: [A Proposal to Add Y Combinator to the Standard Library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0200r0.html)

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Does function has self reference with this? I would like to see reference or tutorial about this kind of thing ,Thanks!

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer: function doesn't have self reference, but as function has a name, it can be (re)used. (non static) methods of class/struct has reference to the class with `this`. lambda doesn't have self reference.